# DB2 SQL query to compare 2 schemas

Tags: sql, schema, db2, compare, schema-compare

I have been unable to find a solution in my searching for this throughout the web, most responses recommend a tool, which leads me to believe this may be very difficult with an SQL query or something, but...

I have been told to write a query for our DB2 database, using Toad to interface, that will compare 2 schemas and provide a result if there are any differences.  I know this capability exists in Toad, but for some reason our DBA does not want to use it.  Purchasing additional software is not an option.

I have very limited SQL knowledge/experience, and this is one of my 'learning' tasks.  I have not made much progress and am feeling very stuck.  Can anyone offer me suggestions?  The help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume by schemas you mean the schemas of a table, right? All that information is available through the views of the `syscat` schema. Look for instance at `SYSCAT.TABLES` and `SYSCAT.COLUMNS`, or see [the documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0001063.htm) for more. You can query those views like any other view/table, so to compare if two tables contain the same columns, you can do something like:

```
  SELECT colname, colno, typeschema, typename FROM syscat.columns WHERE tabname = 'tab1' AND tabschema = 'schema'
  EXCEPT
  SELECT colname, colno, typeschema, typename FROM syscat.columns WHERE tabname = 'tab2' AND tabschema = 'schema'
```

This will, for instance, not return all the columns that are in tab1, but not in tab2.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'll try this out and see where I can get.  There are a lot of tables, so I guess my next step will be to figure out how to make the query sort of dynamic.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try IBM Data Studio, it is free, you can select any 2 objects then compare between them.