# Can schema validation be done using mulesoft?

Tags: schema

I have 2 schemas in the POSTgreSQL database and I need to compare and validate the table ABC in schema 1 and table XYZ in schema 2 using Mulesoft?  Once validation is done write them to log file or XML file.Can you provide some high level steps

Answer (score 0):

With my knowledge i can suggest you build a query to compare two schema s and provide the query to database connector in mule flow.

Which will return expected results.

For reference to query definition please find the below link

[DB2 SQL query to compare 2 schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761672/db2-sql-query-to-compare-2-schemas)

Please let me know if this works for you.